# Function with optional completion block in Swift

Tags: swift, completionhandler

When I create a function, I can make a parameter optional by giving it a default value, like this:

```
func foo(bar: String = "foobar") {}
```

I want to do the same (make it optional) with a completion block. I have tried the following:

```
func foo(completionBlock: (foo: String) -> () = () -> ())
func foo(completionBlock: (foo: String) -> () = (foo: String) -> ())
func foo(completionBlock: (foo: String) -> () = ((foo: String) -> ()))
func foo(completionBlock: (foo: String) -> () = ((foo: String) in))
func foo(completionBlock: (foo: String) -> () = {(foo: String) in})
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** 
This is/was a duplicate question, sorry for that. However, I couldn't find the solution in the original question. So nathan's answer is the best one

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Swift 3:

```
func foo(completionBlock: (String) -> () = { _ in }) {}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this need an @escaping for the completionBlock since it's implicitly non-escaping since Swift3.0?

Answer (score 81):

If you want to default to `nil`:

```
func foo(completionBlock: ((String) -> ())? = nil) {

}
```

If your default completion block is very simple, you can put it right in the function's definition:

```
// A default completion block that is simple enough to fit on one line
func foo(completionBlock: (String) -> () = { result in print(result) }) {
    // ...
}

// A default completion block that does nothing
func foo(completionBlock: (String) -> () = {} ) {
    // ...
}
```

If your default completion block is more complex, you can define it as a separate function:

```
func defaultCompletion(result: String) {
    // ...
}

func foo(completionBlock: ((String) -> ()) = defaultCompletion) {

}
```

Comment: Where should I place the `@escaping` keyword in this case?

Comment: @Rao You don't have to. Optional closures are `@escaping` by default. Read more about it [here](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/why-optional-swift-closures-are-escaping/).